# Angular controller don't run when jump to that page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$scope.logOut = function(){
    console.log('clicked');
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function(res){
        $state.go('intro');
        $rootScope.test = false;

    }, function(error) {
                // An error happened.
    });
}
```

When I click logout, it runs this function and you can see, jump to the Intro page. But when I open the go user profile page. The information still there, however the current user is null.

Comment: Clearing the `cookies` could be the solution...

Comment: When you login using firebase, do you persist the user data somehow? If yes, try unsetting the data...

Comment: You can even use, `firebase.unauth();` in your signout promise.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! Could I try to force to refresh the page when logging out?

Comment: Rayon, do you know how to clear the `cookies`?